# A Lagrange optimisation that I don’t understand. $f(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2$ is constrained by $5x^2 + 6xy + 5y^2 = 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, qcqp

> The function $f(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2$ is constrained by $5x^2 + 6xy + 5y^2 = 1$. Using Lagrange, maximise and minimise this function.

---

My original Lagrange equation was

$$L = x^2 + y^2 + \lambda(1 - 5x^2 - 6xy - 5y^2).$$

After partially differentiating I got:

$$\begin{aligned}
L_x &= 2x - 10\lambda x - 6\lambda y ,\\
L_y &= 2y - 6\lambda x - 10\lambda y , \\
L_\lambda &= 1 - 5x^2 - 6xy - 5y^2 .
\end{aligned}$$

As I’m attempting to find a minimum and maximum, I set all the equations equal to $0$. Rearranging the partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ gave me

$$\lambda = \frac{2x}{10x + 6y}$$

and rearranging the partial derivative w.r.t. $y$ gave me $\lambda = 2y/(10y + 6x)$. Putting these two equations equal to one another gives $$\frac{2y}{10y + 6x} = \frac{2x}{10x +6y}.$$ Multiplying both sides out led to $20xy + 12y^2 = 20xy + 12x^2$. As such I could equate $x$ to $y$.

Subbing in $x$ for $y$ into the constraint gave me $16x^2 = 1$ and as such $x$ (and $y$) $= \pm \frac14$. However, I don’t think either $\left(\frac14, \frac14\right)$ or $\left(-\frac14, -\frac14\right)$ are the minimum and maximum points. If I have done something wrong please correct me but as of right now I am unsure what to do. Also, $z$ being listed in the function but actually having no part in any of the question confused me too. Was just hoping someone could help me understand.

Comment: Please show what you have tried or why you think it may be impossible if you want good feedback.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? the constraint tells you that our points lie on an ellipse and a continuous function on a compact set takes a max and a min.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: the stationary points of the Lagrangian solve a quadratic function in $z:=y/x$.

Comment: Considering $f$ as a function only in $x, y$, it's a continuous function on a compact set (completing the square on the constraint shows that the set of solutions is bounded, and it's obviously closed) so it must achieve both its minimum and maximum.  Please **edit the question** to tell us what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: Maybe you are doing a paper for credit and are fishing for a solution? How can we know if you don't contribute anything?

Comment: the constraint set is an ellipse, draw a careful picture.

Comment: @whpowell96 I’m sorry this is my first time using this site. I have added in all my workings out to the summary to show what I’ve done. Hope this helps.

Comment: @lulu I don’t understand how to get the actual minimum and maximum points

Comment: @J.G. I’m sorry I don’t quite understand what this means? Should i have put my partial derivative for x over my partial derivative for y to get that of z?

Comment: @RobertShore was the z in the f(x, y, z) just put there to throw me off? I have added in what I did for the question.

Comment: @Paul I’m sorry about that, I have now added in what I did for the question.

Comment: @WillJagy I see. Would I have had to draw out the function in order to answer the question?

Comment: Did you mean to write $f(x,y)$ instead of $f(x,y,z)$?

Comment: @AnotherUser I was confused about that as well but the question specifically said f(x, y, z)

Comment: I suppose that that's a typo.

Comment: @AnotherUser Potentially but if so it really threw me off for the entire question

Comment: Another possibility is $ y = - x $, and that leads to $ ( \dfrac{1}{2}, - \dfrac{1}{2} ) $ and $(-\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{2} ) $

Comment: @ghasheem I completely missed that thank you. So that would make (0.5, -0.5) and (-0.5, 0.5) the maximum and (0.25, 0.25) (-0.25, -0.25) the minimum?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.

Comment: Thanks for editing in your work. To answer your question about my previous comment, I was only suggesting a way to rewrite a quadratic equation in $x,\,y$ as a quadratic in $y/x$ only, but the Lagrangian still should be construed instead as a function of $x,\,y,\,\lambda$. By the way, your calculation only shows extrema satisfy $x^2=y^2$, which is compatible with not only $x=y$ (which minimizes $f$) but also $x=-y$ (which maximizes $f$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I can safely assume that $f$ is a function of $2$ variables, rather than $3$.

Let $g(x,y)=5x^2+6xy+5y^2$. Note that
$$
E=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,:\,g(x,y)=1\}
$$
is a compact set (it is an ellipse), and therefore the restriction of $f$ to that set must have a maximum and a minimum. The points at which they are attained are such that $\nabla g=(0,0)$ or that, for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, $(x,y,\lambda)$ is a solution of the system

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
         2\bigl((1-5\lambda)x-3\lambda y\bigr)=0\\
         2\bigl(-3\lambda x+(1-5\lambda)y\bigr)=0\\
         5x^2+6xy+5y^2=1.
       \end{array}\right.\label{sys}\tag{1}
$$

But $\nabla g(x,y)=(10x+6y,6x+10y)$, which is $(0,0)$ only at the origin, which does not belong to $E$. On the other hand, the first two equations of the system \eqref{sys} form a system of two linear equations in two variables depending upon a parameter $\lambda$. The matrix of the coefficients of this system is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1-5\lambda&-3\\
-3&1-5\lambda
\end{pmatrix},
$$
whose determinant is $0$ if and only if $\lambda=\frac12$ or $\lambda=\frac18$. If the determinant is not $0$, then the only solution of the system which consists of the first two equation is $x=y=0$, which is not a solution of the third equation.

Now, suppose that $\lambda=\frac12$. Then the system becomes
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
         -\frac32x-\frac32y=0(\iff x+y=0)\\
         5x^2+6xy+5y^2=1,
       \end{array}\right.
$$
whose only solutions are $\pm\left(\frac12,-\frac12\right)$. And if $\lambda=\frac18$, then the system becomes
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
         \frac38x-\frac38y=0(\iff x-y=0)\\
         5x^2+6xy+5y^2=1,
       \end{array}\right.
$$
whose only solutions are $\pm\left(\frac14,\frac14\right)$. But $f\left(\pm\left(\frac12,-\frac12\right)\right)=\frac12$ and $f\left(\pm\left(\frac14,\frac14\right)\right)=\frac18$. So, the maximum is $\frac12$ and the minimum is $\frac18$.

Comment: Thank you so much. In the second Lagrangian multiplier how did you get the final +y?

Comment: It was a typo. Sorry about that.

Comment: @AnotherUser You need some extra work to actually show that the critical points that you have identified are minimum or maximum points...

Comment: @PierreCarre I have expanded my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: @PierreCarre I did provide that information, when I wrote that the equality $\nabla g(x,y)=(0,0)$ never occurs on the points of the ellipse (since actually it never occurs at any point of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$).

Comment: @AnotherUser You'rr right! didn't notice!